# Syntax error when using Prepare Statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin, prepared-statement

I am trying to make a trigger which will create a File with data from the DB and the file would have a different name every time. I'm trying to put the DateTime but a simple increment would be better although, I don't know how since we can't use any variables. It'd be better in the case where two files are created at the same time. The problem with my code is that I get an error when I'm using the Prepare/Execute statements.

I get 'Syntax error near PREPARE s1...' What's wrong?

```
SET @my_var = 
    CONCAT (
       "SELECT * FROM table_name INTO OUTFILE 'file_path/log-"
       , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d')
       , ".txt'"
    );
PREPARE s1 FROM @my_var;
EXECUTE s1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7.26 and PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: MySQL requires you to end your statements with `;`

Comment: When I execute it automatically removes them.

Comment: What removes them? phpmyadmin? Include what you are trying to execute in the question, not just what it does to it after you execute.

Comment: The code I posted is the same I'm using in phpmyadmin. I'm setting up a Trigger. Everytime I execute the trigger, when it works, it removes every ';'

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you're trying to create it through phpmyadmin, but I would assume some kind of wizard interface since I do not actually see "CREATE TRIGGER" anywhere. Is there a checkbox for "multi-statement", or something for referencing "delimite", and have you tried adding `BEGIN` and `END` to the top and bottom of your code?

Comment: You have to click on the table you want to create the trigger. You'll see a tab called Triggers. When you click on it you can add a trigger and a sort of wizard will appear. In this wizard you choose the name of the trigger, the table on wich the trigger will activate, the moment it will activate (before or after the event) and the code you want to execute.

Comment: And yes, I tried but the wizard does it by itself. Here's an example of code that it creates: `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insertLog`;CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `insertLog` AFTER INSERT ON `access_property` FOR EACH ROW SET @sql_text = CONCAT ( "SELECT * from access_property into outfile 'C:/Users/stagiaire-ing/Desktop/Nouveau dossier/SharedFile/FileWrite/log-" , DATE_FORMAT( NOW(), '%Y%m%d') , ".txt'" )`

Comment: Try adding BEGIN and END to the top and bottom of the code you enter into phpmyadmin.

Comment: I get the same error. Except that it get stuck on execute instead of prepare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is not possible to do [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/596401/sqlplusError-3e-3eplusDynamicplusSQLplusisplusnotp).

The Current MySQL (5.7) Manual section D.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs states that

- SQL prepared statements (PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE PREPARE) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers. Thus, stored functions and triggers cannot use dynamic SQL (where you construct statements as strings and then execute them).
- Generally, statements not permitted in SQL prepared statements are also not permitted in stored programs. For a list of statements supported as prepared statements .
- Because local variables are in scope only during stored program execution, references to them are not permitted in prepared statements created within a stored program. Prepared statement scope is the current session, not the stored program, so the statement could be executed after the program ends, at which point the variables would no longer be in scope.

So you can see that it's not permitted. If someone has an alternative, please comment.

Comment: Nope, you pretty much found the reason for your problem; but now that I think about it, this does seem like a really weird task for a trigger (considering MySQL triggers are executed for every row inserted/updated/deleted). Your data format use suggests maybe you want to look into EVENTs instead.